# Auto naming / symmetrize issues

Tags: rigging

I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFaqjwpGxOc&ab_channel=RoyalSkies

At 1:32 he selects all the bones on the right side of the body. When I do this, it misses a whole bunch of fingers like in the attached pic.

[image]

That's not a huge issue but I'd like to know why it's happening, so selecting those and continuing on...

The next thing he does is use the auto name left/right. This works for me for the most part. Most everything gets "R" appended to the end, but 2 or 3 of them end up with "L". Also not a huge issue but I'd like to know what I'm doing for that to happen.

The next he does is use the symmetrize option, which for me doesn't work. It just pops the bones out slightly from where they are originally, like in the attached image. Is this because all of the names aren't consistent with "R" appended to the end?

[image]

EDIT: Thank you both, your input has been very helpful and has solved my issue. It is indeed due to my character positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your object is facing the wrong direction**

[image]

[image]

If you look carefully, in the tutorial, the model is facing at the negative Y direction but your model is facing the negative X. Try to go to front view from your file and you will understand, you should see your model from the side.

This is the reason why your naming doesn't work correctly :

For the auto naming, Blender will name all the bones on the left with `L` and all the bones on the right with `R`. Where you got it wrong is that Blender considers positive X as left and negative X as right :

[image]

But since your model is facing at Blender's "right", all your bones that are in the front of your model will be named with `R` and all those in the back are named `L`.

This is also what happened when you symetrize. Blender symetrize your bones in the X axis, hence the result that you have.

The solution to your problem is simple : press <kbd>1</kbd> to go to front view and then, rotate your model and armature to face that view, then apply the rotation (it is important to do so). After that, auto-naming and symetrize should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

All symmetrize and autonaming functions need a correct naming convention (you can find  a list of accepted suffix in the Blender Manual, most commons .L .R, .l .r, .Left .Right, ....).

Then all simmetrize functions are oriented on X axis by default, while your model is oriented on Y axis: i.e. your legs went symmetric on X axis. So you have to rotate 90 degrees both character and rig, Apply the rotation, then symmetrize.